# Reverse Relationship with Tastypie, AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I have a resource in which I'm trying to expose its' votes.

```
class ViewPostResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'user',full=True)
    votes = fields.ToOneField('voting.resources.GetVotesResource', attribute='vote_set', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = UserPost.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'posts'
        include_resource_uri = False

class GetVotesResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Vote.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'vote'
```

My vote model is a bit different-than-normal though. How would I expose a post's votes with the following model setup?

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user         = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='vote')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object       = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    vote         = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=SCORES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use "dehydrate" instead:

```
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['votes'] = Vote.objects.filter(object_id=bundle.obj.id, content_type=n).count() // or use aggregate to get total votes.
        return bundle.date
```

Replace "n" with the correct content type.

Comment: I'm not trying to return the count though, I'm trying to return the whole Vote object with user_id and all. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You should still be able to use dehydrate. You just need to map the fields you need one by one. Alternatively, it can be something like bundle.data['vote'] = Vote.objects.get(user=bundle.object.user).__dict__ .

Comment: This lead me in the right direction, but I'm calling .values() on a .filter() instead of .get()- any idea why it's being returned as a dict in a string instead of just a dict?